# How to model many-to-many relationship in frontend (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, model, many-to-many

i'm trying to model a many-to-many relationship from the database in my Flutter application. I have a Recipe model and an Ingredient model in the backend and a RecipeIngredient table models the relationship between the two.

I don't know if the answer if obvious but i want to use the best practices to model this relationship in the frontend. Also, i need to be able to filter the ingredients by recipe in the frontend.

Any suggestions?